# In Django how can I get a widget that accepts an ISO 8601 datetime string and works with a DateTimeField?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I want to submit an ISO 8601 datetime string with a [time zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) to a django form that I am writing. I want to use a standard `DateTimeField` for the datetime but have a widget that accepts such a datetime string. Is this possible, or am I confused about the relationship between Widgets and Fields? How do I do it?

---

Parsing the string is easy, using `django.utils.datepase.parse_datetime`.

I have tried writing a widget like so:

```
from django.forms import HiddenInput
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

class DateTimeInputForMachines(HiddenInput):
    def _format_value(self, value):
        out = super(DateTimeInputForMachines, self)._format_value(parse_datetime(value))
        return out
```

and using it in a `ModelForm` like so:

```
from mywidgets import DateTimeInputForMachines

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['start', 'thing']

        widgets = {
            'start': DateTimeInputForMachines()
        }
```

but the 'start' field fails validation with "Enter a valid date/time."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets are for displaying data, and have nothing to do with validation.

If you just need to input a custom date format, there is no need for any subclassing; you can supply `input_formats` directly on the field (see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield)).

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%z"])

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['start', 'thing']
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `input_formats` wouldn't suffice for such string (from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11385 and others). Will it work with "2015-09-08T01:55:28+08:00" or will I need to convert to UTC first? I'll try it when I next get the chance.

Comment: That is a 5-year-old ticket, which refers to a Python bug which has since been fixed. It turns out though that in Python 2.7 whether `%z` works depends on your system. In Python 3.2+ it will always work.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and this is the way to go. It's not perfect because it turns out python's `%z` is of the form `+0800` instead of `+08:00` which is a pain.